# Script compilation error at declaring repository on gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, repository

I am trying to declare some repositories in my *build.gradle.kts*, but whenever I do `gradle bootRun` I get a script compilation error that I cannot get rid of.

```
 * What went wrong: Script compilation error:
 
   Line 13:             url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"  
                            ^ Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
```

The lines causing the error are these:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" 
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = "1.3.61"))
    }
}
```

I cannot understand what is wrong.

I'm running this from a Powershell.

`Gradle -version` output:

> ---
>
> Gradle 6.6.1
>
> ---
>
> Build time:   2020-08-25 16:29:12 UTC Revision:
> f2d1fb54a951d8b11d25748e4711bec8d128d7e3
>
> Kotlin:       1.3.72
> Groovy:       2.5.12
> Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
> JVM:          1.8.0_252 (Amazon.com Inc. 25.252-b09)
> OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Answer (score 0):

Solved changing the conflicting line to

```
maven {
    url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
}
```

Syntax changed due to using Kotling DSLs instead of Groovy, something I wasn't aware of.